# Union or concat custom data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, union, concatenation

hi im just trying to make it like this in sql

```
SELECT ID,Name
FROM Countrys
UNION all
SELECT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','All' Name
ORDER BY Id
```

to using it with "ALL" option on combobox

```
using (GezentiEntities GE = new GezentiEntities())
{
    string[,] str = new string [1,2]{ {"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "All"} };
    var obj = str.Cast<object>().ToArray();
    var countries = (from c in GE.Countrys select new { c.Id, c.Name })
                    .Concat
                    (from s in obj select s);

     cmbNationality.DataSource = countries.ToList();
     cmbNationality.ValueMember = "Id";
     cmbNationality.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

it gives me that error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: this makes me laugh `from word in obj select word` :))

Comment: @KingKing I liked that too. :) Samet, let me know if my answer covers it, or if I've missed something.

Comment: dont laugh guys, im too new on it and i dont know how its workin yet and @paqogomez its not workin, gives me 2 error Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#2' to 'AnonymousType#1'
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.Add(AnonymousType#1)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your anonymous type query into a list, then use the add method of the list to append an anonymous type.

Note the naming of the variables in the select and subsequent naming in the add to make sure it all matches up.

```
var countries = (from c in GE.Countrys 
                 select new {Id = c.Id,Name = c.Name}).ToList();

countries.Add(new {Id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", Name = "All"});
```

Comment: dont laugh guys, im too new on it and i dont know how its workin yet and @paqogomez its not workin, gives me 2 error Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#2' to 'AnonymousType#1'
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.Add(AnonymousType#1)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: i made it like that 

 Guid Idadd = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
                countries.Add(new { Id = Idadd, Name = "All" });
Thanks @paqogomez.